# android: How do I check that a movie has done playing?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, animated-gif

I am using the following code to run a gif movie

```
if (movieStart == 0) {
  movieStart = (int) now;
}

if (mMovie != null) {
  int relTime = (int) (now - moviestart);

  if (relTime > mMovie.duration()) {
    relTime = mMovie.duration();
  }

  mMovie.setTime(relTime);
  mMovie.draw(canvas, 
      getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2, 
      getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);
```

My movie runs fine. My question is this: How do I know when the movie has finished playing?
(of course I have an action that I need to start when the movie ends.)

by the way, I am using `android.graphics.Movie`

Comment: I never worked with `android.graphics.Movie`, but, supposing your pasted code sits within `onDraw()`, shouldn't the movie have played fully once after `relTime >= mMovie.duration()` evaluates to true ? Your code already check for it, just fire your action instead of `relTime = mMovie.duration();`

Comment: @desseim your suggestion helped. Will you please repost as a response so I may mark this issue as resolved?

Comment: done, thanks for suggesting it and glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your pasted code sits within onDraw(), the movie should have played fully once after `relTime >= mMovie.duration()` evaluates to true.
Your code already checks for it, so you should just fire your action instead of `relTime = mMovie.duration();`:

```
if (movieStart == 0) {
    movieStart = (int) now;
}

if (mMovie != null) {
    int relTime = (int) (now - moviestart);

mMovie.setTime(relTime < mMovie.duration() ? relTime : mMovie.duration());
mMovie.draw(canvas, 
    getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2, 
    getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);

if (relTime >= mMovie.duration()) {
    // move has played once
    fireAction();  // or set a member variable or whatever
}
```